Geo Nodes: Offset value of animated instanced geometry along a curve
In geo nodes I have recreated an absolute shape key animation which follows the profile of a surf wave. I then want to instance this aniamted geometry along a curve and offset the value of each wave profile to create a rigged wave.
I cant seem to work out how to offset the value of each instance, any ideas? Im still fairly new to geo nodes so I might have missed something.

Here is inside the node group

File download
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/diokuxbopxklv7txkiw0m/SurfWaveRig_190724.blend?rlkey=mir9rgnv8uglml4lzf12kvncd&dl=0
-Edit01-
Ok so I tried realising the instances but now the animation only works on one curve and the other curves all scale to 0 at the origin.
I feel like this has something to do with the index order of the verts on my curves. Again I dont really know what I am doing.


Instances share the same vertex data (or control points for curves). The only thing you can change between instances are transforms (location,rotation,scale). In your case, you need to Realize Instances and only then Set Position : Instance on Points > Realize Instances > Set Position. It should solve your issue, otherwise let us know what's wrong.

Thanks for you help. I tried that but it didnt work. I think it might have something to do with the index order?

You can do it this way: https://i.imgur.com/MFHsn00.png of course then you need to use the captured index: https://i.imgur.com/rJi2AGv.png Also please see How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice
